# case in Sql doesnt run as i expect

Tags: mysql, sql

is it wrong if i expect that SQL understands that it should check every single rows to see if S.PersonID is null?

```
select OrderQty as 'OrderQty', 
case  
    when (select S.PersonID from Sales.Customer as S) is null then 1 
    else 2 
end as 'CaseResult' 
from sales.SalesOrderDetail
```

error: Subquery returned more than 1 value.

if it is wrong then why it understands that it should check every rows one by one in the example below?

```
select Name,
case ProductCategoryId
   when 1 then 'red'
   when 2 then 'black'
   else 'white
end as 'categoryname'
from production.productcategory
```

How can i write the first code so that it works like the second code?

Comment: Use `when not exists (subquery) then`. Or even more simple: `SELECT ... , EXISTS (subquery) + 1 AS CaseResult ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use subqueries inside CASE
Also, you are not doing a join between SalesOrderDetail and Customer

```
select OrderQty as 'OrderQty', 
case  
    when s.Person is null then 1 
    else 2 
end as 'CaseResult' 
from sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
left outer join sales.Customer s on sod.PersonId = s.PersonId
```

Comment: You can. But only if they return 1 row only

Comment: correct, but the left outer join is to the customer. If they have the same customer multiple times they are screwed anyway ;-)

Comment: But as a general answer, correct, there is no safety mechanism for multiple rows in the customer table. For a more generic answer (which probably would require an inner join to SalesOrder too) I would do a "with" query and left outer join to it. But now we are getting into deeper waters without knowing the data model, indexes and table sizes.

Comment: No @Tobbi, we can have a subquery inside a Case statement.

Comment: only if they return one row - I'd consider that a bad practice. In general, having a subquery between SELECT and FROM is usually considered bad practice.

Comment: So @Tobbi, in a query , SQL can check a condition in a column, row by row, and it returns a result after checking the condition for each row. we can build a new column with these results.
but, we can not tell SQL to check a condition in rows of a column from a subquery in Case statement. what i wanted to do was that Sql goes and checks a condition in rows of a column in a subquery and return a result after checking each row.

Comment: between SELECT and FROM, no, you can't - in case there are multiple rows. If you just want to check if any row fulfills the requirement then I recommend a CTE but you can also use subqueries in the FROM statement. CTE enhances readability but effectively works the same as subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

You need a correlated subquery, to get it running correctly

```
CREATE TABLe Customer(PersonID Int)
```

```
INSERT INTO Customer VALUEs (1)
```

```
CREATE tABLe SalesOrderDetail ( OrderQty int, CustomerID int)
```

```
INSERT INTO SalesOrderDetail VALUES(2,1),(3,2)
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
select OrderQty as 'OrderQty', 
case  
    when (select C.PersonID from Customer as C WHERE C.PersonID = S.CustomerID ) is null then 1 
    else 2 
end as 'CaseResult' 
from SalesOrderDetail S
```

| OrderQty | CaseResult |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/E55dYyQ2)

If you have a query that has multiple rows as resultset you need to add a LIMIT to the subquery

```
CREATE TABLe Customer(PersonID Int)
```

```
INSERT INTO Customer VALUEs (1)
```

```
CREATE tABLe SalesOrderDetail ( OrderQty int, CustomerID int)
```

```
INSERT INTO SalesOrderDetail VALUES(2,1),(3,2)
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
select OrderQty as 'OrderQty', 
case  
    when (select C.PersonID from Customer as C WHERE C.PersonID = S.CustomerID ORDER BY C.PersonID LIMIT 1) is null then 1 
    else 2 
end as 'CaseResult' 
from SalesOrderDetail S
```

| OrderQty | CaseResult |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f1D_vyij)